# setting div position before animation in react-reveal Fade in animation

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I am trying to do a simple slide in and slide out animation using react-reveal. This is my code snippet:

```
{glanceDataFetching ? null : (<HelperBtn onClick={() => toggleShowHelper()}>{ showHelper ?  (<span>&gt;</span>) : (<span>&lt;</span>)}</HelperBtn>)}
    <Slide right duration={2000} when={showHelper}>
      <InfoBlockContainer>
        <Infotext>
          <span className="mr-1">&#x1F6C8;</span>
          <span>For viewing cataract/retina status, report or for updating call status/visit status, click on the respective cell</span>
        </Infotext>
      </InfoBlockContainer>
      </Slide>
```

Here InfoBlockContainer is a styled component with following styles:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height: 65px;
border: 1px solid #36A2EB;
background-color: lightblue;
border-radius: 4px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 5px;
padding: 5px;
```

And this is the animation result I am getting (Intentionally added a duration of 2sec to show case the issue):

[image: Slide In Div]

As it can be seen that after it slides in it moves downwards a bit as per the css and places itself to it's correct position and same when it slides out. Which doesn't look smoother at all. How can I fix it? Or start the animation of div with the position it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably as `InfoBlockContainer` is absolute positioned at 0 from bottom, when sliding in and out it creates overflow on containing block. As a result scroll bars are produced. When `InfoBlockContainer` comes in, scrollbars are removed so it moves downward a bit.

To fix, I suggest to add `overflow: hidden` to nearest absolute positioned containing block. If all containers of the `Slide` are not absolute positioned, add `overflow: hidden` to the `body`.

Here is a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/animationwithabsolutediv-lpqty). If you remove `overflow: hidden` from the `body` element, you'll see the same placement change like you're expecting.